# How to receive slf4j logging and still do not depend on logging backend?

Tags: java, logging, remote-debugging, slf4j

I am using [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org) as logging facade and let users decide where and what to log. Now in case of a crash, I want to send a file to the server that contains debugging information--which basically means a log-file. And since we already have all that log-statements scattered in the code, why not use them?

So basically, I want to create a log file programmatically via SLF4J, transparent for the user who still can plug in his own logging backend and configuration.

My first idea was to implement the `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder`, deliver my own implementation of a logger that does its logging and then delegates to the user-configured logger. However, I see certain issues with this: If the user puts a normal logging backend, then multiple instances of `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` are on the classpath. This will issue a warning AND I might not be able to make sure, that my implementation is the one to get called.

Are there better solutions to this? A whole different approach? Is the idea inherently bad? How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SLF4J is open-source, you can modify it to use another class than `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder`. Then your custom `StaticLoggerBinder` class could load the original, user-provided `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` (if it exists).

Another idea is using a custom `LoggerFactory` (not `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory`) in your application which returns a `Logger` delegate. This delegate class delegate logging method calls to the original `Logger` implementation and also sends the logs to the server if it is necessary.

Anyway, both would look an awkward hack to me, creating two artifacts (one for end-users and another one for developers) smells better.

(Finally, I don't know what kind of library/application it is, but in my working environment it would not be acceptable if a library sends data to a third party server. Are you sure that you really need to to do this?)

Answer (score 3):

The point of SLF4J is not to let application end-users choose their logging framework (why would they care?) but to let developers include a library without being tied into the library's choice of logging framework.

So if you want to upload debug information from a deployed application, it's fine to fix the logging implementation. The user can still edit the implementation's configuration file, if they want.

Comment: I totally agree on your first point. However, the app can be used in two ways: for an end-user and with an API for developers to be included in other applications. Even if it is used as an API, I'd still like to have a copy of the log of our app AND I'd like to avoid having two different versions just because of this functionality.

Comment: @roesslerj this is a detail you may want to edit into the question itself.